# Kali linux shutting down network after 5 minutes

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, networkmanager

So recently i installed Kali linux on my computer ( along with Windows 10 dual boot )
In the installation process i couldn't get past the network configuration for wifi no matter what, i had to use ethernet to install the distro
The installation was a success but whenever i turn on my laptop Wifi works for 5 minutes then stops, the network manager stays active but i can't connect to any wifi or ethernet no matter what
Tried to restart networking and NetworkManager services but didn't solve the problem
Tried reinstalling the driver but couldn't ( the commands gave me errors and exited )

PS: ifconfig shows all info normally

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the wireless card has drivers for Kali. Not all wireless cards are supported by Kali.

Here is a list of supported cards:

[Wireless Cards for Kali](https://www.kalilinux.in/2022/04/wifi-adapter-for-kali-linux.html)

I use a Panda USB wireless adapter and it installs and works, and supports monitor mode.

Chipset is important but most cards that support Kali have supported chipsets.

Numerous cards that will not install use Chipsets that do not work with Kali.

In your case, perhaps try a supported USB Wireless card to replace the one you are using.

Posted from my Kali 2023.2 VM.